# Cast HTML5 video to Chromecast natively from Chrome Desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, video, android, chromecast

When playing HTML5 Video in Chrome for Android (via `<video>`-Tag) while having an active Chromecast dongle in the local network it displays the "Cast" icon in the upper left corner of the video. In the desktop version of chrome this does not seem to be possible. There is only the option to cast the whole tab which means that a live capture of the tab will be locally streamed to the Chromecast. Although this also results in the video and audio being played on the Chromecast it means that your computers screen will be captured, reencoded and then be transmitted to the Chromecast whereas Chrome for Android instructs the Chromecast to play the original Video source directly from the Internet (like all the other Chromecast Apps like YouTube, Netflix, etc.).

Why ist this feature not available in Chrome Desktop while it **is** generally possible to talk to Chromecast in this "native" way judging by YouTube's or Netflix' sites which offer their "Cast" feature also in Chrome Desktop?

Comment: Just for completeness: When pointing the browser directly to a video's URL, the "Cast" icon will be in the lower right corner beside the controls of the native player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how you'll feel but you can check out "[Videostream for Google Chromecast™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/videostream-for-google-ch/cnciopoikihiagdjbjpnocolokfelagl?utm_source=gmail)":

Comment: Yeah, that one is doing essentially the same thing. I was just wondering why Chrome devs wouldn't include in Chrome Desktop by default while they do in Chrome for Android. But since I asked the question the way I did, I will mark your post as an answer. Thx!

Comment: @Arminius I feel, like many of their products, Google devs are little clueless  about what to do with the chromecast next :), It is quite expected for a company which develops so so many things at a time without thinking whether it may or may not be commercially viable, that's what it makes Google - a Google.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now it can. Just play any video, while you're casing the tab with Chromecast. If you zoom to fullscreen, it will switch to streaming the video only, not the tab. Earlier it was a hidden feature, see https://www.xda-developers.com/chromes-dev-channel-adds-a-hidden-media-remoting-feature-for-chromecast/